# Dataframe merge creates multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})    
right = pd.DataFrame({'key': [ 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})

df = left.merge(right, on='key', how='outer', indicator=True)
df
```

[image]

This always creates value_X and value_y column, is it possible to have only one value column with merge?

Comment: can you show how you want the result to look like ? i dont understand 'is it possible to have only one value column with merge?'

Comment: you want something like this ? https://imgur.com/a/IAb1aMV

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some thing like this, or please share how you want your output to look like :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})    
right = pd.DataFrame({'key': [ 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})

df = pd.concat([left,right])
df
```